# Why do i get Windows error 2 when i am using pyserial with arduino?

Tags: python, arduino, pyserial, usbserial

I send data from Python to Arduino MEGA 2560 via usb serial Interface. Everything worked for months without any problems. But a few days ago it just does not work anymore and always comes in the attachment error message. I have tried to change the serial port number, so it works only once and when i reran the code the error message comes again. I am using pyserial 2.7 32 bit on Windows 7 and Arduino MEGA 2560 COM7 is defined in the device manager. 
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kQ2ei.png)

```
import serial #Serial imported for Serial communication
import time #Required to use delay functions

ArduinoSerial = serial.Serial('com7',9600)
time.sleep(0.5)
```

Comment: Maybe we can help if you show some of your code ;-)

Comment: if your press on the picture you will see everything

Comment: Please include the complete error traceback **as text** in your question itself, not as an image.

Comment: Could you try to list the availible serial ports ?

python -m serial.tools.list_ports

https://pythonhosted.org/pyserial/shortintro.html#listing-ports

Comment: The error indicates that the port name is **incorrect**. Go to device manager and double check the port name. Also, I suggest you try to change the port name to something else.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add:

```
ArduinoSerial.close()
```

At the end of your code for the port to be closed and available again.

Otherwise just close the Python IDE console and run from your editor again.

Comment: i closed the IDE console thats not the reason.

Comment: And have you verify the process has been completely shut down with task manager? It sure seems you have it stuck somewhere